# Can someone help me establishing the polarity of this dc jack on my laptop motherboard?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, dc, computers, laptop

So my laptop charger port is fried and I wanted to establish the polarity of the points on the board so I can solder a off the shelf jack instead of the original one which is not available anymore. I will use the original charger and replace the tip on its end to match the new jack so there shouldn't be any voltage/amperage issues. Here are the pictures of the same.
[image]

[image: The photo of my charger and the the kind of plug I wanted to replace current jack with]

Comment: The polarity isn't important to know ***as long as*** you match the pin/shield connections of the new jack to that of the old one.

Comment: Check to see if the current charger has markings on the *brick* part showing the polarity of the lines for the charger tip. The receptacle on the laptop has to have matching polarity.

Comment: I'd say that the 1969 moon landing pictures were better quality than those.

Comment: It's right there on the label. Centre +ve, outer -ve.

Comment: @AJN I have included the charger picture and the jack I'm intending to use picture in the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the charger end and you can determine the polarity with a multimeter.

In fact, the information is often printed on the power supply centre pin positive or negative... positive centre is most common but never guaranteed so always check.

Your port looks like it is rectangular so check.

Comment: Added the charger photo seems like it's center positive , right? Also regarding the kind of jack I'd need,I was thinking of soldering wires to the board and then soldering the jack to it , instead of onboard.

Comment: @JDoe9999 that charger pic shows centre positive. So you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated.